# Object passing to an arrow function with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

#### Problem: how can I pass a object from a parent component to its child component that is derived from the same interface?

I am trying to render a list of tasks by iterating over a list of task objects.
The problem is happening when I try to pass each object individually to the child component.

- I know instead of passing an object I could pass the attributes of this object separately.

But is there any solution to pass an entire object?

**Parent**

```
import {task} from "../structs/types";
import Task from "./Task"

interface TasksProp{
    tasks: task[]
}

const Tasks = (props: TasksProp) => {
    return (
        <>
            {props.tasks.map((t: task) => (
                <Task key={t.id} task={t}/>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default Tasks
```

**Child**

```
import { task } from "../structs/types"

const Task = (t: task) => {
   return (
       <div className='task'>
           <h3>My Task</h3>
       </div>
   )
}

export default Task
```

**Task Interface**

```
export interface task {
    id: number,
    text: string,
    day: string,
    reminder: boolean
}
```

Comment: *(t: task)* - props object isn't task, it's an object that contains task key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not receiving the `t: task` in the props correctly in your child component. Change to this:

**Child**

```
import { task } from "../structs/types"

interface ChildProps {
 task: task,
};

const Task = (props: ChildProps) => {
   // destructure your props
   const { task } = props;

   return (
       <div className='task'>
           <h3>My Task</h3>
           <!-- Use your task, this is just an example -->
           <span>{task.text}</span>
       </div>
   )
}

export default Task
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer explicitly annotating the function component using React.FC

### Parent

```js
interface ParentProps {
  tasks: task[]
}

const Tasks: React.FC<ParentProps> = ({tasks}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tasks.map((task, ind) => <Task key={ind} task={task} />)}
    </>
  )
}
```

### Child

```js
interface ChildProps {
  task: Task
}

const Task: React.FC<ChildProps> = ({task}) => {
  ...
}
```